# Particle system Not following mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, particles, hair

[image: Head has left mesh]I made hair using hair particle system but once I rig and animate. The hair does not follow the mesh. What do I do?

I added an image. I hope it helps you understand it better. I made the hair using the particle system. So I really don't understand why it is not moving the rigged mesh. Only the base mesh follows the amarture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've seen something like this, IIRC, it was related to the dynamic hair cache.

Comment: We would like to help you, but this question is vague and unspecific. Could you please at least edit the question so it has pictures of the problem.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter It's edited

Comment: @RonJensen I haven't added any dynamics to the hair .

Comment: Would you mind putting the .blend file here? This is more complicated then I expected at first.

Comment: Okay. Here is a link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdvOSebGbOZQq_T9u9KEqXjGhxXoTZ_0/view?usp=sharing   Let me give a bit more information. I don't know if it's necessary. But I have disabled all unnecessary components from viewports. There are 2 armatures; one animated from Mixamo and the second a rigify metarig that copies the first. There are 4 particle groups; Hair, scalp, beard and brows. All of them don't move.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter Have you seen it?

Comment: Actually, I think I found the error. I fixed it. The problem was in the order of modifiers. The particle system came before the armature deform. I dragged it down as the last modifier and it worked.

Comment: Nice! Sorry I missed that .blend file 2 hours ago. I wasn't on Blender-SE. Nice you found the answer. Could you put it in an answer so this question won't be in the unanswered stack anymore?

Comment: Happy Blending! 

Answer (score 0):

The modifiers are in the wrong order. The particle system is coming before the armature deforms modifier. Drag the particle system below the armature deform so that it follows the armature deformation.